# innerHTML is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="col-md-3 list">
                <form style="width:300px;">
                    <span>Add a list…</span>
                    <input id="list_id" type="text" name="list_name" placeholder="Add a list…" autocomplete="off">
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="addList(document.getElementById('list_id').value);">
                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>    

<div class="list" id="board">
        <div id="todo">
            content
        </div>
    </div>
```

Content is not adding in dom.. It is coming but after some time going off.
Please help!!

```
var lists = [];
    var items = [];

    function addList(val) {

        //var e = document.getElementById('list_id');
        //var val = e.value;
        // Do the rest here
        /*
        <div class="list">
                <div class="list-header js-list-header non-empty u-clearfix editable">
                    <h2 class="list-header-name hide-on-edit js-list-name current">hsdfds</h2>
                    <p class="list-header-num-cards hide js-num-cards">0 cards</p>
                    <span class="list-header-subscribe-icon icon-sm icon-subscribe js-list-subscribed hide"></span>
                    <div class="edit edit-heavy u-clearfix">
                        <textarea class="field single-line" type="text"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <a class="list-header-menu-icon icon-sm icon-dropdown-menu dark-hover js-open-list-menu" href="#"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="list-cards u-fancy-scrollbar u-clearfix js-list-cards js-sortable ui-sortable"></div>
                <a class="open-card-composer js-open-card-composer" href="#">Add a items�</a>
            </div>
        */

        lists.push(val);

        var cartHTML = '<div class="list">';
        cartHTML += '<div class="list-header js-list-header non-empty u-clearfix editable">';
        cartHTML += '<h2 class="list-header-name hide-on-edit js-list-name current">' + val + '</h2>';
        cartHTML += '<p class="list-header-num-cards hide js-num-cards">0 cards</p><div class="edit edit-heavy u-clearfix"><textarea class="field single-line" type="text"></textarea></div>';
        cartHTML += '<div class="list-cards u-fancy-scrollbar u-clearfix js-list-cards js-sortable ui-sortable"></div><a class="open-card-composer js-open-card-composer" href="#">Add a items�</a>';
        cartHTML += '</div></div>';

        addListsContent(cartHTML);

        //return true;
    }

    function addListsContent(cartHTML) {
        document.getElementById('todo').innerHTML = cartHTML; //cartHTML;
    }
```

Comment: Where is your element with id todo?

Comment: <div id="todo"> is present in html page

Comment: pls tell me why it is not working

Comment: I will try after sometime. Right now leaving for somewhere. Will be back in an hour.

Comment: the main issue is you have a submit button but you are not stopping default behavour (see my updated answer)

Comment: You just need to change the type of button from submit to button

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code

you are passing through `document.getElementById('list_id')` (a html element) to the function `addList` but you are then trying to display it in your string `'<h2 class="list-header-name hide-on-edit js-list-name current">' + val + '</h2>'` .

you'd need to pass `document.getElementById('list_id').value` if you want to pass the value to your function/array.

With this change it works as you'd expect. and maybe rename the varaibles so that it makes sense etc

You also have used a submit button as your click handler. Default behaviour is to submit/refresh the page. You'll need a button to stop the page refreshing as you are not preventing default. Here's a [working fiddle](http://atmd83.jsbin.com/jekaba/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I am passing addList(document.getElementById('list_id').value); only

Comment: updated. here is a working fiddle http://atmd83.jsbin.com/jekaba/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering of two things -

- Your button is of type submit so it's submitting your form. Do you want to submit?
- Why you are passing "val" while constructing your html string? I believe that you want to add value of that text input which can be done as val.value.

So I guess removing of "submit" type and adding val.value should help you.

```js
var lists = [];
    var items = [];

    function addList(val) {

        //var e = document.getElementById('list_id');
        //var val = e.value;
        // Do the rest here
        /*
        <div class="list">
                <div class="list-header js-list-header non-empty u-clearfix editable">
                    <h2 class="list-header-name hide-on-edit js-list-name current">hsdfds</h2>
                    <p class="list-header-num-cards hide js-num-cards">0 cards</p>
                    <span class="list-header-subscribe-icon icon-sm icon-subscribe js-list-subscribed hide"></span>
                    <div class="edit edit-heavy u-clearfix">
                        <textarea class="field single-line" type="text"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <a class="list-header-menu-icon icon-sm icon-dropdown-menu dark-hover js-open-list-menu" href="#"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="list-cards u-fancy-scrollbar u-clearfix js-list-cards js-sortable ui-sortable"></div>
                <a class="open-card-composer js-open-card-composer" href="#">Add a items�</a>
            </div>
        */

        lists.push(val);

        var cartHTML = '<div class="list">';
        cartHTML += '<div class="list-header js-list-header non-empty u-clearfix editable">';
        cartHTML += '<h2 class="list-header-name hide-on-edit js-list-name current">' + val.value + '</h2>';
        cartHTML += '<p class="list-header-num-cards hide js-num-cards">0 cards</p><div class="edit edit-heavy u-clearfix"><textarea class="field single-line" type="text"></textarea></div>';
        cartHTML += '<div class="list-cards u-fancy-scrollbar u-clearfix js-list-cards js-sortable ui-sortable"></div><a class="open-card-composer js-open-card-composer" href="#">Add a items�</a>';
        cartHTML += '</div></div>';

        addListsContent(cartHTML);

        //return true;
    }

    function addListsContent(cartHTML) {
        document.getElementById('todo').innerHTML = cartHTML; //cartHTML;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 list">
                <form style="width:300px;">
                    <span>Add a list…</span>
                    <input id="list_id" type="text" name="list_name" placeholder="Add a list…" autocomplete="off">
                    <div>
                        <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="addList(document.getElementById('list_id'));">
                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>    

<div class="list" id="board">
        <div id="todo">
            content
        </div>
    </div>
```